# Save serial data to web server database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, serial-port

I am new to this, so any thoughts are much welcomed. :)

What I am trying to do is to read serial data via an RS232 cable going into the COM1 of a laptop and then saving this data into a web server database of some kind.  I think MySQL is the way to go as to store my database.  However, I don't see much documentation on how I can automate streaming in the serial data into the database.  I only found this [webpage](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=186884) that says it is possible.  Any thoughts?  Pointers to tutorials and/or reference?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll need a script/program to sit in the middle, collecting serial data and writing to the database. What platform are you on, and what programming languages are you good with?

Comment: I will probably be using a linux laptop (Ubuntu) and I am ok with C.  Learning java currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is a relational database. Is the data you read on the serial port relational? From your usage of words, I doubt it.
If it is some kind of measurement data you need to store for a specific interval, the "Round Robin Database" might be a better choice. It even offers the option of storing old data with less resolution using less disk space.

If you insist on using mysql, you probably want to collect the data for a while, and save a standard sized chunk as a "binary large object" along with a timestamp.

Comment: This program RRDtool looks promising as well.  Can the graphs be added on a website?

Comment: Sure, that's what it was designed to do originally, within the MRTG web application.

Answer (score 1):

A few questions come to mind - are you able to develop and install software solution or you want to create this with off the shelf tools?

If you are allowed to install custom software - reading from RS-232 and connecting to mysql is really simple with C# so the whole program will be less then a hundred lines of code. You just read the stream and from time to time insert it into the table with strucure like that id,datetime,TEXT. Depending on the nature of the stream you can insert on number of bytes/time elapsed or some logical condition.

Comment: I am able to install custom software, so this might be a good deal.  Now, I just have to research on how to get the data to the mysql database.